# Select count(*) from table where (multiple id) in (table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to write

```
SELECT count(*) from tablename where (multiple_ids_here) in (SELECT id from tablename)
```

Normally, I would write:

```
select count(*) from tablename 
where id_1 in (SELECT id from tablename)
OR id_2 in (SELECT id from tablename)
id_3 in (SELECT id from tablename)
```

which very inefficient if we have multiple values.

Anyone?

**EDIT:** Question updated. What if I want to select count?

Comment: Can't you use a JOIN?

Comment: sure. if that would be better.

Comment: can you elaborate little more what the issue you are facing ? of course yu can write 3 different in statements

Comment: That query will either return 0, or the number of rows in the table... Doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the updated question regarding getting a `count(*)`... using [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) with `values()` to unpivot your data in a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
;with cte as (
  select t.Id, v.RelatedId
  from t
    cross apply (values (id_1),(id_2),(id_3)) v(RelatedId)
)

select 
    cte.Id
  , RelationCount = count(*)
from cte
  inner join RelatedTable r
    on cte.RelatedId = r.Id
group by cte.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

Your version with three `in`s is probably the most efficient way of doing this.  If you want a comparison to try, you can use `exists`:

```
select . . .
from t t1
where exists (select 1
              from tablename t2
              where t2.id in (t1.id_1, t1.id_2, t1.id_3)
             );
```

I should also note that storing ids in multiple columns like this is usually a sign of a problem with the data model.  You probably want a table with one row per id, rather than one column per id.  Such a format would also simplify this type of query.

Comment: the ids are the same columns for a table but are different items. ie. Person1, SisterofPerson, Brother, etc.. but they are on the same `Person` table

Comment: what if I want to use count? I'll update the question.

Comment: What if someone has two sisters?  A relationship table makes more sense.

Comment: there is a relationship table. and having multiple sisters is handled well. (though `Persons` is just an example)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand your question could you give an example of the data you are using and the out come.

From what i understand you could use a cte like this  .

```
;WITH Sales_CTE ([counts],CustomerID, SalespersonPersonID,PickedByPersonID)
AS
(
   select count(*),CustomerID,SalespersonPersonID ,PickedByPersonID 
   from [WideWorldImporters].[Sales].[Orders]
   group by CustomerID,SalespersonPersonID,PickedByPersonID
)
SELECT sum([counts])
FROM Sales_CTE
GO
```

It would give you a result like this . You would jsut have to change the columns around .

[image]